# How to add date and place for an article(upcoming event) in gk news module (joomla 2.5)?

Tags: joomla, feed

How can I add date and place for my articles which are announcments for upcoming events in gk news mod to look something like this module

[image]

(picture from this page http://www.ktabkbih.net/)?

Comment: You question would be best aimed at the developer of the extension. Either that or try something yourself and show some code ;)

Comment: It's a commercial extension, why not ask the developer? Else extend the model and view to handle the extra info, and share your work if you want help. I hope you understand we're not going to purchase the extension to see if we can help figure out your issue.